# Force chrome to start an entirely new process when opening a new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

If i have the following small JS function

```
function newWin() {
var win = window.open("www.google.com") //should open new tab in chrome
}
```

When running this chrome will group memory into one process for any new tabs opened.

Is there anyway to force this opened window to not share memory with it's parent?

Comment: This sounds like an [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/249013). If it is, please ask a new question with the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

I found a 2009 page stating that it can be done like this

> Now, thanks to a new HTML 5 feature that got implemented in the latest
>   builds of the Webkit HTML engine, which powers Chorme, Safari and a
>   bunch of desktop and mobile browsers, developers can make links on
>   their sites open in a new process adding a new level of protection.
>   All they need to do is add the new rel="noreferrer" attribute as well
>   as a target=”_blank” to their links pointing to another domain.
>
> Read more:
>   http://news.softpedia.com/news/Force-Google-Chrome-to-Open-Links-in-New-Processes-128962.shtml#ixzz46RXwpFl0

Also, a comment on the same page says:

> You can force Chrome to open each new tab in a new process:
>
> "If you add the string '-process-per-site' to the Target line, Chrome
>   will open a new process for each tab, but if you open the same site in
>   two tabs, it will run them on the same process. The string
>   '-process-per-tab' will force Chrome to create a completely new
>   process and use a new memory space for each tab, which is its
>   default."
>
> http://www.techradar.com/news/internet/10-really-cool-google-chrome-hacks-501492?artc_pg=2
>
> Read more:
>   http://news.softpedia.com/news/Force-Google-Chrome-to-Open-Links-in-New-Processes-128962.shtml#ixzz46RYCBXua

Comment: Can I use rel=noreferrer from a window.open function or does that need to be part of a html link to function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

@Sim  you cannot use `rel=noreferrer` from a `window.open`, but you can create a link with jquery, do a click event and remove the element instead